# Embedding tableau views in webpage using HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, tableau-api

I understand to the point that it is possible to embed the tableau view using an HTML code that looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tableau/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js">
<div id="tableau_view" class="tableauPlaceholder" style="width:1028px; height:804px;">
  <object class="tableauViz" width="1028" height="804" style="display:none;">
    <param name="host_url" value="http%3A%2F%2Ftableau%2F" />
    <param name="site_root" value="" />
    <param name="name" id="wbName" value="view_0&#47;view_0" />
    <param name="tabs" value="no" />
    <param name="toolbar" value="yes" />
  </object>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to generate a page with dropdown menu that contains the value of the "name" parameter.  Basically, when I select a value in the dropdown, that would refresh the segment of the page with the tableau viz that is associated with the selected value.  I have been struggling with this for while, as I am still learning JavaScript myself.

This is what I have right now:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tableau Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tableau/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js">
    function selectViz() {
        var mylist=document.getElementById("tableau_workbook");
        var wbName=document.getElementByName("name");
        wbName.setAttribute("value",mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].value);
     }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
    <!-- Dropdown Menu, the value corresponds with those found in the "name" parameter in the tableau view code -->
    <select id="tableau_workbook" onchange="selectViz()" >
        <option>Choose Workbook</option>
        <option value="view_0&#47;view_0">bioapps_single</option>
        <option value="view_1&#47;view_1">bioapps_merged</option>
    </select>

    <!-- Tableau view goes here -->
    <div id="tableau_view" class="tableauPlaceholder" style="width:1028px; height:804px;" >
        <object class="tableauViz" width="1028" height="804" style="display:none;">
            <param name="host_url" value="http%3A%2F%2Ftableau%2F" />
            <param name="site_root" value="" />
            <param name="name" value="view_0&#47;view_0" />
            <param name="tabs" value="no" />
            <param name="toolbar" value="yes" />
        </object>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

At this point I don't have the access to Tableau JavaScript API, so I am trying to do everything using raw HTML/JavaScript.  Not really sure whether I am doing this right or not.  Your help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Young

Answer (score 6):

I think I will post the code that I created as a reference for others to view if they get into the same sticky situation as I did.  Like I have mentioned, I have figured out way to access tableau javascript api, and the code below is using it.  Please keep in mind this is for embedding the views in a webpage.  There is slightly different way of doing this in Confluence Wiki Page, which is described [here](http://community.tableausoftware.com/message/260786#260786).

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tableau Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tableau/javascripts/api/tableau_v8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function selectViz() {
    var mylist=document.getElementById("workbook_selection");
    wbValue = mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].value;
    wbTagQuote = wbValue;
    initializeViz(wbTagQuote);
}

function initializeViz(wbTagQuote){
    var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
    var url = wbTagQuote;
    var options = {
        width: placeholderDiv.offsetWidth,
        height: placeholderDiv.offsetHeight,
        hideTabs: true,
        hideToolbar: true,
        onFirstInteractive: function () {
            workbook = viz.getWorkbook();
            activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();
        }
    };
    var viz = new tableauSoftware.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<!-- Dropdown Menu, the value corresponds with those found in the "name" parameter in the tableau view code -->
    <select id="workbook_selection" onchange="selectViz()">
        <option>Choose Workbook</option>
        <option value="view_0&#47;view_0">view_0</option>
        <option value="view_1&#47;view_1">view_1</option>
    </select>
<!-- Tableau view goes here -->
    <div id="tableauViz" style="height:1200px; width:1200px"\"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Important: under option value, you insert the link to your tableau view (i.e. "http://" followed by tableau_server_name/path_to_view).  Also, the dropdown menu at current state is not fully functioning...while first element has been selected, when you try to load another view, it will not work...I am trying to figure this out.

Comment: This was very useful for me, as a BI techie with little knowledge of javascript. `Error`: When the dropdown was being changed, the code was failing. This was happening because their was already a Viz in the div where we have tableau report embedded. Added a viz dispose, which `fixed` the issue mentioned of current state not being functioning by you. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't strictly answering your question, but if you don't have local access to the Tableau Javascript API, then it should be possible to test using the Tableau Public version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://public.tableausoftware.com/javascripts/api/tableau_v8.js"></script>
```

In terms of reference material, check out the following links for more details on how to use the Tableau Javascript API (my internet connection is terrible right now, so I'll post more reference links tomorrow, and an attempt at properly answering your question)

- [Javascript API tutorial](http://www.tableausoftware.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/javascript-api-intro-and-embed)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.  The only issue with using the Tableau Public version is that the data being showed is somewhat confidential.  I haven't said this in the earlier post, but the webpage is created within a Confluence Wiki page that is used within the organization for whom I am working.  So as much as I would like to take the Tableau Public route, it is a no-go.  Nonetheless, thank you again.

Comment: The workbook has to be published somewhere before it can be embedded somewhere else. If you're not using Tableau Public, do you have access to Tableau Online or an on-premise installation of Tableau Server?

Comment: Yes, I do have on-premise installation of Tableau Server.  The workbooks are already published on the server, just that I would like to have the workbooks embedded on the website, as I have already described before.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question...I want to somehow write a JavaScript/HTML code such that when I select something on a dropdown menu, I can change the "value" attribute of the parameter, "name".  For example, <param name="name" value="view_1" /> to <param name="name" value="view_2" /> and refresh the Tableau viz on the page with the selected viz.

Comment: Whilst this may be possible using raw HTML and Javascript (I'm not having much joy right now), it would be significantly easier using the Tableau Javascript API. Is there a good reason for not using the API?

Comment: Hi, until few days ago, I couldn't get the API to work, and was assuming that there was something wrong with on-premise installation of the Tableau Server.  Just got everything to work, and now struggling to embed the API script to Confluence Wiki page.